# measure any functions running time, and getting functions return value

Tags: c++, templates, boost, void

I've a class to store one function, and when its called it stores the function's running time.
And it's good on void return type functions. But when i want to get the stored function's return type, i've got a 'void value not ignored as it ought to be'. I can't specialize the template because return types aren't covariant (as far as i understand).

So the following class is bad.

```
class TimeDurationOperation {
public:
    TimeDurationOperation(boost::function<void(void)> operation_)
        : operation(operation_) { }

    template <typename R> R operate() {
        const boost::posix_time::ptime start =
            boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time();

         R return_value = operation();

        const boost::posix_time::ptime stop =
            boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time();
        elapsed = stop - start;
        return return_value;
    }

    boost::posix_time::time_duration elapsed_time() const {
        return elapsed;
    }

private:
    boost::function<void(void)> operation;
    boost::posix_time::time_duration elapsed;
};
```

Working versions operate() function:

```
void operate() {
    const boost::posix_time::ptime start =
        boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time();

    operation();

    const boost::posix_time::ptime stop =
        boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time();
    elapsed = stop - start;
}
```

I want to call it like this:

```
TimeDurationOperation tdo(boost::bind(detail::fun1, 2000));
tdo.operate();
std::cout << tdo.elapsed_time() << std::endl;
```

and

```
TimeDurationOperation tdo2(boost::bind(detail::fun2, 500));
int r = tdo2.operate<int>();
std::cout << tdo2.elapsed_time() << " and returned: " << r << std::endl;
```

What's your suggestions?

Comment: Use a `template typename <T>` and then use `T` instead of `<void(void)>`, perhaps? I'm no expert on templates, so I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Did you mean that I should template my TimeDurationOperation class with the function's signature? Because it won't work since I call the function object like this: `operation()`.

Comment: Well, that was my suggestion, yes. But if that doesn't work, then you may need to find a different way to solve the whole problem...

Comment: The covariant restriction only applies to virtual functions, of which templates aren't (under any sane circumstances)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so this post is a bit old but I think it would be helpful to post an answer.

Using modern C++ (11/14) this task is very easy.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <functional>

template <typename Ret, class... Params>
struct TimeDurationOperation {
    explicit TimeDurationOperation(std::function<Ret(Params...)> operation)
        : operation(operation) { }

    template<class R = Ret>
    typename std::enable_if<!std::is_void<R>::value, R>::type operate(Params... vals) {
        auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        R return_value(operation(std::forward<Params>(vals)...));
        auto stop = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        elapsed = stop - start;
        return return_value;
    }

    template<class R = Ret>
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_void<R>::value, void>::type operate(Params... vals) {
        auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        operation(std::forward<Params>(vals)...);
        auto stop = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        elapsed = stop - start;
    }

    const std::chrono::duration<double>& elapsed_time() const {
        return elapsed;
    }

private:
    std::function<Ret(Params...)> operation;
    std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed;
};
```

You can use this the following way:

```
int return_test_function(int i) {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(20ms);
    return i * 2;
}

TimeDurationOperation<int, int> tdo(return_test_function);
auto result = tdo.operate(21);
auto elapsed = static_cast<double>(duration_cast<milliseconds(tdo.elapsed_time()).count());
```

With variadic templates you can represent any parameter list.
With std::function you can represent any function. Simple functions (pointers) implicitly converted to this type.
SFINAE implementation with std::enable_if. If the expression in the enable_if is false the function is not compiled. Try to use the "wrong" function with a template will result on a compiler error (or warning, depending on the compiler).
You can measure elapsed time with std::chrono.

Note: this solution uses the standard only. No third party library (like Boost) needed.

Answer (score 0):

For type safety, you're going to want TimeDuration to know the return type.  It's also more useful if it knows the parameters:

```
template<class signature> class TimeDurationOperation;

template<class Ret, class...Params>
class TimeDurationOperation<Ret(Params...) {
public:
    TimeDurationOperation(boost::function<Ret(Params...)> operation_)
        : operation(operation_) { }

    Ret operate(Params... vals) {
        const boost::posix_time::ptime start =
            boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time();

         R return_value = operation(std::forward<Params>(vals)...);

        const boost::posix_time::ptime stop =
            boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time();
        elapsed = stop - start;
        return return_value;
    }

    boost::posix_time::time_duration elapsed_time() const {
        return elapsed;
    }

private:
    boost::function<Ret(Params...)> operation;
    boost::posix_time::time_duration elapsed;
};
```

Now as to the actual problem: Template specialization is the first and most obvious thing.

```
template<class...Params>
class TimeDurationOperation<void(Params...) {
public:
    TimeDurationOperation(boost::function<void(Params...)> operation_)
        : operation(operation_) { }

    void operate(Params... vals) {
        const boost::posix_time::ptime start =
            boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time();

         operation(std::forward<Params>(vals)...);

        const boost::posix_time::ptime stop =
            boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time();
        elapsed = stop - start;
    }

    boost::posix_time::time_duration elapsed_time() const {
        return elapsed;
    }

private:
    boost::function<void(Params...)> operation;
    boost::posix_time::time_duration elapsed;
};
```

Alternatively, (though I would consider this a terrible idea) one could abuse destructors.

```
    struct RAII_timer {
        RAII_timer(boost::posix_time::time_duration& dest) 
            : start(boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time())
            , elapsed(&dest)
            {}
        RAII_timer(const RAII_timer& NO_COPIES) = delete;
        RAII_timer& operator=(const RAII_timer& NO_COPIES) = delete;
        ~RAII_timer() {
            const boost::posix_time::ptime stop =
                boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time();
            *elapsed = stop - start;
        }

        boost::posix_time::ptime start;
        boost::posix_time::time_duration* elapsed;
    };
    Ret operate(Params... vals) {
        RAII_timer timer(elapsed);
        return operation(std::forward<Params>(vals)...);
    }
```

Comment: Using `RAII_timer` seems to be an elegant way to take care of computing the elapsed time. Why do you consider it a terrible idea?

Comment: @RSahu: Because it's being used as a way to execute invisible code, as opposed to cleaning up resources.  Destructors should be used for cleanup, not executing normal code.

Comment: Hmmm... That's an interesting perspective. I have used them in many places where constructor is treated as 'initializer' and destructor is treated as 'finalizer'.